# Can I clone the VPN settings on network manager to create new settings on the same user/machine?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have a VPN with multiples servers for multiples locations.

I need to create a VPN entry for each location which would all use the same settings:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9B5p.png

  But a different server address:
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/3789u.png

Is there an easy way to do this that doesn't imply setting up every server again and again?

I tried going to Network Manager Settings on /ect/NetworkManager/system-connections and duplicating the entry, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you are using city codes to differentiate your gateways.  Here is one way you can use from the command-line to quickly achieve your goal.  I will assume that `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/vpn-file` is where your current configuration lives.

```
export VPNFILE=/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/vpn-file
for city in LON TYO BOS HNL; do
  sudo cp -iv $VPNFILE $VPNFILE-$city
  sudo nano $VPNFILE-$city # make the changes you want and save the file
done
sudo service network-manager restart
```

That should do it.  Make sure you slightly change the uuid in each file.  Let me know if something is unclear or if you run into problems.

If you are not familiar with nano you can replace nano with gedit or any other editor you like.  Saving in nano is by default via Ctrl+O and you close the file via Ctrl+X.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Just out curiosity, there was a way to also automate what you edit on the file with nano?

Comment: Great.  If this worked for you, it would be nice to mark this question as solved. To answer your follow-up question, yes, of course you can automate those changes instead of using nano or any other editor for that matter.  sed might be a way to do that.  It depends on your level of expertise with those tools relative to the level of complexity of your changes.  There are many ways to skin the cat.